# Spring transaction creation

Tags: spring, cglib

This question was asked me in one interview

```
class A{
   @Transactional
   public void test1(){
      test2();
   }

    @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED.NEW)
    public void test2(){}
}



class B extends A{

   public void test1(){
      super.test1();
     }
}
```

He asked me how many transaction objects would be created? The answer was 1, not 2. now I am having a hard time struggling with this part. He said this is how *CgLib proxy* works, can anyone explain this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program can be rewritten like:

```
class A{
   @Transactional
   public void test1(){
      this.test2(); // this is added
   }

    @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED.NEW)
    public void test2(){}


class B extends A{

   public void test1(){
      super.test1();
     }
```

suppose you get `A` from application context and call the `test1()` method on that:

```
 var a = context.getBean(A.class);
 a.test1()
```

we know that `a` is actually the **proxy object** so a transaction is going to be created. in `test1()` method we call `this.test2()` method.

From Spring doc:

> However, once the call has finally reached the target object any
> method calls that it may make on itself, such as this.bar() or
> this.foo(), are going to be invoked against the this reference, and
> not the proxy

so  for `test2()` method no transaction is going to be created because this is invoked against the `A` class not the proxy class with all transactional stuff support.

Now suppose that you get `B` from application context and invoke `test1()` method against it.

```
 var b = context.getBean(B.class);
 b.test1()
```

Because `B` is the subclass of `A` and `A` is annotated with Transactional, `B` itself is a proxy (@Transactional is automatically inherited even though test1() in `B` is not annotated with `@Transactional`). so a transaction is going to be created. when we reach the target object all transaction stuff goes away and no more transaction is going to be created like the first case.

Comment: so in both cases, the only transaction will be created right? if yes, what is use Required.NEW?

Comment: @LowCool suppose we are in a method that is annotated with `Required` and call another method that is annotated with  `Required.NEW` (not directly but using proxy object like `productRepository.saveItem(item)`) . if there is an exception in `saveItem` it is going to rollback only the new transaction created by  `Required.NEW`  and operations that were performed in `saveItem`  method are rollbacked.  operations that are performed by first transaction remains intact. but if save method is annotated by `Required` and a exception was thrown, then ALL operations are rollbacked

Comment: just one last question, can you please refer me some book or documentation where I can learn more?

Comment: @LowCool There are lots of blogs and youtube videos about the subject. Spring in Action in my opinion is a good book